# HOMFLY polynomial of hopf link

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

I have this Hopf link https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mCxI.jpg and when I try to calculate the HOMFLY polynomial I get the standard answer but with negative powers of l i.e. ml^{-1} + m^{-1}(l^{-1}+l^{-3}). Is this because of the specific orientation or have I made a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: Can you say exactly which version of the HOMFLY polynomial you are calculating?  There are multiple conventions.  Please also give the polynomial as you calculated it along with the polynomial you are comparing it to.

Comment: It's the one on the wikipedia page. The polynomial is P(Hopf) = ml^{-1} + m^{-1}(l^{-1}+l^{-3}).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of "Homfly polynomial for the Hopf Link." This question is asking about an orientation issue and why the exponents came out differently.

Answer (score 1):

Using $\ell P(L_+)+\ell^{-1} P(L_-)+m P(L_0)=0$ and $P(\text{unknot})=1$, I get $\ell^{-3}m^{-1}+\ell^{-1}m^{-1}-\ell^{-1}m$ for the Hopf link.

[image: Hopf link HOMFLY calculation]

This uses that the HOMFLY polynomial for the split link of two unknots is $\frac{-\ell-\ell^{-1}}{m}$, which either comes from the split link formula or a quick calculation:
[image: HOMFLY of split link of two unknots]

HOMFLY of the Hopf link with one of the components reversed in orientation gives the same polynomial but with $\ell$ and $\ell^{-1}$ swapped.